# MySQL Multiple Join/Subquery Questions

Tags: sql, mysql, join, subquery, duplicates

For about a year now, we’ve been allowing our users to login with usernames and/or email addresses that are not unique (though each user does have a unique id).  Although the system handles duplicate usernames/emails elegantly, we’ve decided to finally enforce unique usernames and email addresses.  I’ve been tasked with generating a table in MySQL that will show the duplicates and the tables in which a duplicate’s id is being used (i.e. the tables dependent on the duplicate’s user id, using 1 for true and 0 for false).  This table will then be used as a reference once duplicate data is marked for deletion.  In short, I’m looking to generate a table something like this:

| User_id |
    Username |
    Email |
    Exists_in_Table1 |
    Exists_in_Table2 |
    Exists_in_Table3 |
  
  
  
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  
  
    | 0001.....|
    test1.........|
    email.|
    0..........................|
    0..........................|
    1..........................|
  
  
  
    | 0002.....|
    test2.........|
    email.|
    0..........................|
    1..........................|
    1..........................|
  
  
  
    | 0003.....|
    test3.........|
    email.|
    1..........................|
    1..........................|
    1..........................|

It doesn’t matter much how this is accomplished.  Since my SQL skills are somewhat lacking, I intended to do this programmatically using PHP and a number of simple SQL queries.  However, I believe a single SQL query or a series of queries (without the use of PHP) is the cleanest approach.  I know how to query for duplicates, but I can’t seem to figure out how to query multiple tables and join them by the user id in an appropriate manner.  I appreciate any and all help with this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT u.User_id, u.Username, u.Email,
 IF(t1.User_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS Exists_in_Table1,
 IF(t2.User_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS Exists_in_Table2,
 IF(t3.User_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS Exists_in_Table3
FROM Users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 t1 USING (User_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 USING (User_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 t3 USING (User_id);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, such a fast response!  I'll be trying this as soon as I'm back at the office.